# access sql text not available for listbox

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a SQL server-backed Access database, and I'm struggling with one of my tables, "Notes".

My database has a Profile form for each user, and on their profile, I want to display notes from the Notes table.  My notes table is set up like this:

NoteID (PK) int  
GoerID int
NoteType int
Note (***????***)
StaffID int
Timestamp datetime

My issue is with the Note format.  I can get a query to pull all information, but when I try to use a listbox to display the query info, the Note field is NOT available to add to the listbox.

I'm sure it's likely this is due to the field type, but I've tried every type I can think of.  ntext, text, nchar, etc.  Basically, I need this note field to have around 200 characters of variable text and be displayed in the listbox.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Updated with screenshot of table and datatype settings in Manager Studio:
[Screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4ynq.jpg)

Also note that  I've rebuilt the table several times (when changing datatypes), and in the screencap, the NOTE field is actually named [NoteText]

Comment: What is the datatype in SQL Server?

Comment: For my note field?  My last attempt was nchar(256),  Tried ntext and text as well.

Comment: Assuming you are using `MS sql server`, get someone to use "SQL Server Management Studio", have them open the database and table that you are pulling [Note] from and tell us what that data type is.  Knowing the data type of your source will eliminate a lot of guessing.

Comment: Just posted a screencap (see above) of the table settings and datatype (or so I think) from microsoft management studio.

Comment: You could be running into Unicode problems. Is there a reason you are using `nchar(256)` instead of `char(255)` on the SQL server side?  Also be aware that Access data type of "Text" has a maximum of 255 characters.  If you want 256 or more, you need to use the Access data type of "Memo" in your destination table.

Comment: Use `varchar(255)` or (if you need Unicode) `nvarchar(255)`. That will translate into Text(255) (resp. Short Text) on the Access side, and should work with your listbox as well.

Comment: Boom!  varchar did the trick.  Thanks so much, team!

Comment: @prsaddict  Don't forget to mark the correct answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `varchar(255)` or (if you need Unicode) `nvarchar(255)`.

That will translate into `Text(255)` (resp. `Short Text` in newer Access versions) on the Access side, and will work with your listbox as well.